# another equality of two functions

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, functional-equations

In one of my previous posts (see here [proving equality of two functions.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2278640/proving-equality-of-two-functions/2278704#2278704)) I asked if. $f,g$ are two functions from $\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ satisfying $f•g=g+1$ and $g•f=f+1$ then $f\neq g$ in general. Suppose I tweak the conditions a little bit Say we have $$f(g(n))=f(n)+1$$ and $$g(f(n))=g(n)+1$$ what happens now ? Is $f=g$ ?

Comment: If f=g, then you tweaking is meaningless.

Comment: but these are two new conditions . And u have to prove or disprove that f=g before u can say it

Comment: I mean suppose f=g, then solutions for these would the same as your last question, as there f=g solutions to those? If not, you would not have here too.

Comment: Can u give a proof please ?